# Typescript error in React Table example when converting file to tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I'm playing around with the React Table [examples](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/examples.md), Edit Table data, and noticed a Typescript error if I convert the example to tsx.

https://codesandbox.io/s/green-cloud-2r6zc

This useTable hook contains the autoResetPage which Typescript does not like:

```
const {
    ...
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn,
      autoResetPage: !skipPageReset, // Type error!
      updateMyData
    },
    usePagination
  );
```

I get the error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'autoResetPage' does not exist in type 'TableOptions<object>'
```

The project still works but if I want to implement the example in a strict Typescript project this won't compile.

What can I do to fix the type error?

Comment: Found solution to this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Managed to work around this, declaring the options object separately and adding it to useTable. For some reason ts compiler are not complaining anymore...